# Calling JavaScript event from GO WebAssembly

Tags: go, webassembly

In JavaScript `events` are vey common that can be called as:

```
<p id="p_id">
</p><button id="some_id">Click me</button>

var element=document.querySelector("#some_id")
var listener=element.addEventListener('click',function(event){  
     document.querySelector("#p_id").innerHTML = "Hello World";                   
 });

// OR
<p id="p_id">
<button onclick="some_function()">Click me</button>

<script>
function some_function() {
  document.querySelector("#p_id").innerHTML = "Hello World";
}
```

I aware with typical JS functions, we can use `js.Global().Get().Call()` and `js.Global().Get().Invoke()` in GO, as:

```golang
//go:build js && wasm

package main

import (
    "syscall/js"
)

var (
    document js.Value
)

func init() {
    document = js.Global().Get("document")

}

func main() {
    c := make(chan int) // channel to keep the wasm running, it is not a library as in rust/c/c++, so we need to keep the binary running
    
    alert := js.Global().Get("alert")
    alert.Invoke("Hi")    
    
    h1 := document.Call("createElement", "h1")
    h1.Set("innerText", "This is H1")
    h1.Get("style").Call("setProperty", "background-color", "blue")

    <-c
}
```

To add `eventListner` from GO, I know we can do it as:

```golang
var cb js.Func
cb = js.FuncOf(func(this js.Value, args []js.Value) interface{} {
    fmt.Println("button clicked")
    cb.Release() // release the function if the button will not be clicked again
    return nil
})
js.Global().Get("document").Call("getElementById", "myButton").Call("addEventListener", "click", cb)
```

What I'm looking for, is how to response from GO to the even that is triggered in JavaScript.

**UPDATE**

To wrap up, how can I write a `go` code to do the same of the `JavaScript` code below (Which is using IndexedDB API):

```
function remove() {
    var request = db.transaction(["employee"], "readwrite")
    .objectStore("employee")
    .delete("00-03");
    
    request.onsuccess = function(event) {
       alert("Kenny's entry has been removed from your database.");
    };
 }
```

Any thought?

Comment: I'm not sure to follow, you mean call a Go function from JS?

Comment: @GustavoKawamoto I updated my question, hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your even is an attributable variable (e.g. `request.onsuccess = function() { ... }`) you can use `Set` to define a `js.FuncOf` to handle the result as a javascript function would, something like:

```
req := js.Global().Get("db").Call("transaction").Call("objectStore").Call("delete")
var f js.Func
f = js.FuncOf(func(this js.Value, args []js.Value) interface{} {
    defer f.Release()

    js.Global().Call("alert", "Kenny's entry has been removed from your database.")
    return nil
})
req.Set("onsuccess", f)
```

Don't forget to `Release` the function once you're done ;)

Comment: Thanks, can you help with this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69976232/2441637

Comment: Can you help with: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69981089/2441637