# How can I use js.Value as argument to js.Global().Get

Tags: go, webassembly

Trying with GO WebAssembly accessing the browser IndexedDB, with the below code I was able to create the ibdexedDB, but I got an error while trying to access it using `js.Global().Get(dbx)` or even trying to access `this.result`

```golang
//go:build js && wasm

package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "syscall/js"
)

var dbOk, dbErr js.Func
var db js.Value

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello WASM")
    db = js.Global().Get("indexedDB").Call("open", "Database", 1)

    dbOk = js.FuncOf(func(this js.Value, args []js.Value) interface{} {
        defer dbOk.Release()
/* Here I've an error */
        dbx := this.result
        fmt.Println("this is: ", dbx)
/**********************/
        js.Global().Call("alert", "ok.")
        return nil
    })
    db.Set("onsuccess", dbOk)

    dbErr = js.FuncOf(func(this js.Value, args []js.Value) interface{} {
        defer dbErr.Release()

        js.Global().Call("alert", "sorry.")
        return nil
    })
    db.Set("onerror", dbErr)
    
    /* This line is wrong, can not access `db` */
    js.Global().Get(dbx).Call("transaction", "readwrite").Call("objectStore", "employee").Call("add", `{ id: "00-01", name: "Karam", age: 19, email: "kenny@planet.org" }`)

    c := make(chan int)
    <-c
}
```

The error I got is:

```sh
# command-line-arguments
./wasm.go:21:14: this.result undefined (type js.Value has no field or method result)
./wasm.go:41:17: cannot use dbx (type js.Value) as type string in argument to js.Global().Get
```

To map it with JavaScript, I wanted this `go`:

```golang
    dbOk = js.FuncOf(func(this js.Value, args []js.Value) interface{} {
        defer dbOk.Release()
        dbx := this.result
        fmt.Println("this is: ", dbx)
        js.Global().Call("alert", "ok.")
        return nil
    })
    db.Set("onsuccess", dbOk)
```

To be equivalent to this JavaScript:

```
var dbx

request.onsuccess = function(event) {
    dbx = request.result;
    console.log("success: "+ dbx);
};
```

And this go code:

```golang
js.Global().Get(dbx).Call("transaction", "readwrite").Call("objectStore", "employee").Call("add", `{ id: "00-03", name: "Karam", age: 19, email: "kenny@planet.org" }`)
```

To replace this JavaScript code:

```
dbx.transaction(["employee"], "readwrite")
    .objectStore("employee")
    .add({ id: "00-03", name: "Karam", age: 19, email: "kenny@planet.org" });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context, `this` is a Javascript object, so you have to get the property `result` of it:

```
result:=this.Get("result")
```

The `result` will be a `js.Value`, and you can get the the Go value of it if it is a primitive, or descend to further object elements using `result.Get()`, or `Call` a method of it.

Comment: That's as lot, worked perfectly

Comment: Can you help with: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69981089/2441637