# Using optional parameters in wasm building

Tags: go, webassembly

I'm trying to convert the below code from IndexedDB JavaScript API into GO WASM:

```
request.onupgradeneeded = function(event) {
    var result = event.target.result;
    var objectStore = result.createObjectStore("employee", {keyPath: "id"});
    
       objectStore.add({ id: "00-01", name: "Karam", age: 19, email: "kenny@planet.org" });
 }
```

So, I wrote:

```golang
    var dbUpgrade js.Func
    var result, request js.Value

    dbUpgrade = js.FuncOf(func(this js.Value, args []js.Value) interface{} {
        defer dbUpgrade.Release()
        result = this.Get("result")

        var objectStore = result.Call("createObjectStore", "employee")
        objectStore.Call("add", `{ id: "00-01", name: "Karam", age: 19, email: "kenny@planet.org" }`)

        window.Call("alert", "First record posted.")
        return nil
    })
    request.Set("onupgradeneeded", dbUpgrade)
```

But i got the below runtime error:

```sh
panic: JavaScript error: Failed to execute 'add' on 'IDBObjectStore': The object store uses out-of-line keys and has no key generator and the key parameter was not provided.
```

I understand the reason is because of not including `{keyPath: "id"}` at `result.Call("createObjectStore", "employee"` to match the JavaScript one, but I tried the below and nothing worked:

```golang
// 1.
result.Call("createObjectStore", "employee", "{keyPath: `id`}")
// 2.
key, _ := json.Marshal(map[string]string{"keyPath": "id"})
result.Call("createObjectStore", "employee", key)
// 3. 
result.Call("createObjectStore", `"employee", "{keyPath: "id"}"`)
```

Any thought how to make it?

Comment: have you tried `result.Call("createObjectStore", "employee", map[string]interface{}{"keyPath": "id"})`

Comment: @blackgreen tried it now, and it is ok, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the documentation for `ValueOf`:

https://pkg.go.dev/syscall/js@go1.17.3#ValueOf

This should work:

```
result.Call(...,map[string]interface{}{"keyPath": "id"})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is fine now.